# Count of crashes and injuries?

Tags: r, dataframe, count, sum, rowsum

I have a dataset from dot.gov website that I have to analyze as part of our school project. It contains a lot of information, but I am just focusing on crashes and injuries. How do I count the number of crashes or injuries from the year 2007-2014 for example?

Do I have to subset my data per year or is there a more efficient way to do it? Thank you!

Below is a sample of my dataset:
[image: Sample dataset]

Comment: Instead of pasting an image of our dataset, can you provide a reproducible example of your dataset using `dput` as described in this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without a reproducible example of your dataset on which we can test our code, it is difficult to be sure that it will be working, but using `dplyr` and `lubridate` package, you can try (assuming that your dataset is called `df`):

```r
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
df %>% mutate(YEARTXT = ymd(YEARTXT)) %>%
  mutate(Year = year(YEARTXT)) %>%
  filter(Year %in% 2007:2014) %>%
  summarise(INJURED = sum(INJURED, na.rm = FALSE),
            CRASH = sum(CRASH == "Y"))
```

To get the count of Crash and injured by per year, you can add `group_by` to the following sequence such as:

```r
df %>% mutate(YEARTXT = ymd(YEARTXT)) %>%
  mutate(Year = year(YEARTXT)) %>%
  group_by(Year) %>%
  filter(Year %in% 2007:2014) %>%
  summarise(INJURED = sum(INJURED, na.rm = FALSE),
            CRASH = sum(CRASH == "Y"))
```

If this is not working, please provide a reproducible example of your dataset: [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: This worked! I have an additional question, how do I get my total crash and injuries per year using code similar to this? Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome ;). I edited my answer to provide you a way to get the count per year. Let me know if it is working.